# Rails specify layout for static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout

My application has some static content:

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'
```

I want these pages to share a layout rather than duplicate the header / footer in each file.

The only documentation around layouts I have found seems to indicate that I should specify my layouts at the controller level, is that correct?

If so, how should give my static pages layouts? The only workaround I see is to create a bunch of empty controllers for each page, for the sole purpose of specifying a common layout file, but that smells like overkill.

Am I missing a trick?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could use a single static controller.

Comment: Yes, just noticed rails already generated a pages controller that I can use for this! Brainfart on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, set the layout at the controller level. You could create a controller for this group of pages like this:

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
    layout "about"

    def about
    end

    def contact
    end

    def help
    end
end
```

I tend to use the name "AboutController" for this sort of thing, to avoid confusion with truly static files that don't pass through a controller at all. But you could name it whatever you like.

Point your routes at it (e.g. `about#contact`). Then create the layout in `app/views/layouts/about.html.erb`

If you ever need to change the layout for a particular action, you can use the `render` method's `:layout` option:

```
def something_special
    render :layout => "other"
end
```

You can also pass false if you don't want a layout at all, like for robots.txt.

Comment: You also can specify like this:    render layout: "other"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set one layout (for example no layout) for all your static pages create a file `config/initializers/high_voltage.rb` and put

```
HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.layout = 'your_layout' # false for no layout
end
```

from https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#override

Answer (score 0):

Per GoodEnough's comment, you could use a gem like [high_voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage)

It defaults to using the "application" layout, but you can change this in one of two ways:

## One layout globally

`HighVoltage.layout = 'foobar'` - if all of your static pages have the same layout

## Varying layouts

Create a PagesController of your own:

```
class PagesController < HighVoltage::PagesController
  layout 'foobar'
```

See the **Override** section of the [docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) for the full scoop.