# Adding a New Controller Brings a new Devise Authentication Error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working on a Rails app that I have co-coded with another Jr. developer.

I want to add a static home page and a static help page to the application.

Following Hartl's instructions (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages#cha-static_pages) I added a static pages controller to the application for home and help pages. When I navigate to static_pages/home I get this error:

```html
NameError in Static_pages#home

Showing /vagrant/src/statuscaster2/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #34 raised:

undefined local variable or method `devise_mapping' for #<#<Class:0xb9d6860c>:0xb9d7ad34>
Extracted source (around line #34):

31:           <% if user_signed_in? %>
32:             <%= link_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
33:           <% else %>
34:             <%- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
35:               <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(resource_name) %>
36:             <% end -%>
37:           <% end %>
```

Devise isn't happy. Line 31 is asking the application if the visitor is signed in and trying to log the user out if they are registered. Line 33 sends visitors to an opportunity to register.

I don't know how to handle this and would be grateful for assistance from the SO community.

Comment: guessing that devise isn't set up properly for your new static pages. You could use another layout for them or make sure that your StaticPagesController is set up in the same way as other controllers in the application. (Assuming that there is other stuff in there that uses devise succesfully.)

Comment: Yes, I agree that devise is not set up to handle the static pages.  Not sure what you mean by setting up the controller the same way as the other controllers are.

Comment: In most setups all controllers inherit `ApplicationController` that helps with this. (I don't remember how it is normally done with devise though.) Your error appears in the common layout that is used by default. If you don't care about logged in users in this case you could either:
(1) add a check if it is a static page to the `if` in your markup or
(2) use a different layout for static pages with maybe the common stuff in a partial

Comment: That's it! Your explanation did it for me. I will post an answer to my own question, but you deserve all of the credit. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of froderik (see comments in question) I have figured this out.

I was thinking about things the incorrect way, trying to blame devise, when it was only doing what it was told to do. My new static pages were utilizing the application layout, by default. This loaded my application's navbar. That navbar is full of devise authentication logic.

By creating a new layout for static pages, and then telling my static pages controller to use that layout, I was able to solve my problem.

The first answer on this post offers additional/related information.

[Rails specify layout for static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836741/rails-specify-layout-for-static-pages)